# How to identify the model/version of a Game Boy cartridge without its sticker?

Tags: version-differences, game-boy

I've started collecting old GB games not long ago.

I found out that there are different versions of each games, for example I have 2 versions of Sneaky Snakes: DMG-NK-FAH and DMG-NK-NOE.

[image: Sneaky Snakes cartridges front]
[image: Sneaky Snakes cartridges back]

I bought a couple of cartridges without stickers, and I wonder if it is possible to identify the version of the game?

Comment: You bought some game cartridges without stickers - are they also Sneaky Snake carts? If not, can you share what game they are? Version Identification techniques may vary between different games.

Comment: No, I just chose this game as an example. I bought two Pokémon Red, one DMG-APAF-FRA, and the other one without a sticker. I'm no expert but since I have games where you can choose the language at the start, and this Pokémon starts directly in french with the text "version rouge", I think it is also a DMG-APAF-FRA. I was looking for a universal technique for future purchases, but if it differ from game to game, I'll have to search for each one :-)

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was a way other than the labels since most cartridges are the same mass manufactured shell with only the actual chips inside changed.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this is late, but I think others might benefit from this information too.

After a closer inspection inside some of my carts the ROM chip has the first two parts of the code and some number, possibly version (usually 0).

For instance, my Mariokart Super Circuit GBA has:
AGB-AMKE-USA on the label and,
AGB-AMKE-0 on the chip

The 3-letter country code is missing, but the previous letter (at least for GBA games) actually indicates the region (E = America, P = Europe & Australasia, J = Japan, etc). I have a limited number of GB cartridges, but the ones with 4 lettered game codes seem to follow the same system, but the games with only 2 have a different rule. I only have two such games:

DMG-ML-CAN becomes DMG-MLA-1
DMG-YO-UKV becomes DMG-YOX-0

So all I have so far is A = Canada and X = United Kingdom (maybe).

If you have a larger collection you can probably work out the region from that. I hope this is helpful!

EDIT: [more info about specific country codes here.](http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=5&threadid=92793)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if there is an engraving on the back of the cartridge or maybe on the very end of the front of it.
If it is without a transparent case maybe its beneath it but be careful if you try to take it out.

Comment: I edited my question with the back of the cartridges, there is no engraving anywhere on them. I'll take them apart when I'll receive the screwdriver I ordered online.
A colleague suggested me to make a dump of the ROM of the game, but this looks not easy and expensive, do you think the ROM will be different for each version?

Comment: @Ulrizza I’m not too sure about that but it could be